# Beautiful Soup 4 sorting tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this page for the menu items with bs4, http://138.23.12.141/foodpro/shortmenu.asp?sName=University+of+California%2C+Riverside+Dining+Services&locationNum=03&locationName=A+-+I+Residential+Restaurant&naFlag=1&WeeksMenus=This+Week%27s+Menus&myaction=read&dtdate=1%2F4%2F2016.

I'm able to scrape the individual menu items with the following code:

```
 import requests, bs4, re

aiMenu = requests.get('http://138.23.12.141/foodpro/shortmenu.asp?sName=University+of+California%2C+Riverside+Dining+Services&locationNum=03&locationName=A+-+I+Residential+Restaurant&naFlag=1&WeeksMenus=This+Week%27s+Menus&myaction=read&dtdate=1%2F4%2F2016')

aiMenuSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(aiMenu.text)
rawBreakfast = aiMenuSoup.select('.shortmenurecipes')
breakfast = str(rawBreakfast)

menuItems = 14
for i in range(len(breakfast)):
    printVersion = rawBreakfast[i].getText()
    print(printVersion)
```

What I want to do is have them under their meal times and the headers. How would I use bs4 to do that?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what _exactly_ is it that you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

You need something more complicated to get it.

I used `lxml` instead of `bs` to can use `xpath`

```
import requests
import lxml, lxml.html

url = 'http://138.23.12.141/foodpro/shortmenu.asp?sName=University+of+California%2C+Riverside+Dining+Services&locationNum=03&locationName=A+-+I+Residential+Restaurant&naFlag=1&WeeksMenus=This+Week%27s+Menus&myaction=read&dtdate=1%2F4%2F2016'

response = requests.get(url)

html = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)

columns = html.xpath('//td[@width="30%"]')

for col in columns:

    meal_times = col.xpath('*//div[@class="shortmenumeals"]/text()')

    for x in meal_times:
        print(x)

    rows = col.xpath('*//tr')

    for row in rows:

        headers = row.xpath('*/div[@class="shortmenucats"]/span/text()')

        for x in headers:
            print(x)

        titles = row.xpath('*/div[@class="shortmenurecipes"]/span/a/text()')

        for x in titles:
            print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Which version for Python is this written in? I'm using 3.5 and cannot find a compatible version for lxml.

Comment: I tested it on 2.7.11 and 3.4.3. If you don't need the newest function available only in 3.5 like `async` and `@` (matrix multiplication) then you can use 3.4. If you use Linux then you can install many versions using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)